# Скорость работы базы данных PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Есть огромный список городов, его нужно отобразить на часто посещаемой странице.
Я могу сделать города просто списком в исходном коде сервера

```
TOWNS_LIST = [
'Москва',
'Сургут',
'Тюмень',
# и т.д. вообщем больше 1000
]
```

либо использовать базу данный (postgresql) для этого.

Города отображаю на странице (это шаблон django):

```
<select name="town>
    {% for town in towns %}
    <option value="{{ town }}">{{ town }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Что лучше использовать? Может быть есть другой способ дать пользователю страницы выбрать определенный город?

Comment: Настройте кэширование в django-проекте - это значительно ускорит работу проекта в целом.

Comment: Список больше 1000 городов, который влезает на одну страницу - это крошечный список...

Comment: У меня в одном проекте например список отдается клиенту по отдельному AJAX запросу. при этом клиент кеширует его у себя в localStorage и помнит номер версии каждого списка. Сервер же вместо готового выпадающего списка отдает только заготовку с пометкой версии справочника на его стороне. Если версия у клиента отличается, он ее перезапрашивает.

Comment: Что касается в коде или в БД думаю разница не большая. Особенно если приложение стандартное, с новой загрузкой интерпретатора питон при каждом обращении. В БД удобнее, если они еще где нибудь в выборках используются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация при помощи кэша:

```
def get_towns_from_cache():
    obj = cache.get('towns') # получаем список из кэша

    if obj is None: # если он отсутствует:
        obj = Towns.objects.all() # получаем список городов
        cache.set(
            'towns', obj, # закидываем этот список в кэш
            60 * 30 # на 60 секунд * 30 = 30 минут
        )
    return obj
```

Как настроить кэш можно найти тут: [Setting up cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache)

P.S. Можно и вовсе обойтись [кэшированием самой вьюхи](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache), если там нет никаких форм или элементов, с которыми пользователь будет взаимодействовать.